# WOTLK Changing reputation from The Oracles to Frenzyheart Tribe when already at 999/1000 exalted

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am playing WOTLK expansion and I have character with 999/1000 exalted reputation with The Oracles in Sholazar Basin and I want to switch to Frenzyheart Tribe, but I am not getting the quest after killing that elite in the cave and killing Jaloot.

I have read somewhere that it's not available if I don't have "[A Hero's Burden](https://www.wowhead.com/quest=12581/a-heros-burden)" quest completed, but I can't complete it as I am already exalted with The Oracles and I can't accept the quests required for this quest to be available.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I can't take that quest since it's from a companion that I get from some item from one of the NPC of that faction. And according to EveryQuest addon I don't have it completed.

Comment: @Matej Wait for daily reset. Also make sure to dmg that elite slowly -  If you kill the Lich before he becomes immune to damage the quest will not appear.

Comment: I tried doing this like 5 days in a row and nothing. Also I always killed him slowly so he becomes immune.